# random displaying of webms

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to display webms on my homepage in a random order
every time someone access the homepage.

i already managed to display a webm just using html via src
but thats only one webm and not multiple
 the problem i have is to make the connection between the html source and my js file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script src="scripts/randomwebm.js"></script>

<div class="window" id="videos" style="display: none;">
      <div class="content">
        <center>
          <video width="500" controls>
            <source id="random_webm" src="" type="video/webm">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 or .webm video.
          </video>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
WHAT MY JS LOOKS LIKE AT THE MOMENT

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",  function(){
function rndwebm(max) {

var src = ["videos/ship.webm", "videos/ira.webm"];   
  return rndwebm.src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)];
src = rndwebm(3);
document.getElementById("random_webm").src = rndwebm(3); 
}});
src = rndwebm(3);
document.getElementById("random_webm").src = rndwebm(3);
```

old version just here to get reference

```
var vid = document.getElementById("random_webm");
var source = document.getElementById("random_webm");
var src = ["videos/ship.webm", "videos/ira.webm"]; 
var s = 0;

  window.onload = function(){
  random_webm.src = src[++s%src.length];
  vid.load();

  }

var webm = new Array();
webm[1] = 'ship.webm';
webm[2] = 'ira.webm';

document.getElementById('random_webm').innerHTML = "videos/" + webm[(Math.random()*1000)%webm.length];
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt at picking a random element at all

Comment: `random_webm.src = src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)]`

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand what you mean by "to make the connection between the html source and my js file" but any way if you want to use JavaScript inside HTML there's two methods 
First: place all your JavaScript codes in .js file and in the head tag include your .js file path

Second: place your code inside script tag in the HTML page

```
<HTML>
<script> java codes </script>
```

I noticed that you didn't use script tag in your code so add it and try

About the code itself i didn't try it to figure out but it seems close as you use getelemntbyid and window.load so it somehow might work

Comment: what i mean by saying "to make the connection between the html source and my js file" is in c# and other programm languages you have methods/classes that can return values, i want my script to return a source(file path), that my html code <source> can use to display a webm, for now i got the random thing going and i get a return "videos/x.webm" i have two questions now, how can i be sure that my function will be executed and how do i give my html the return value i got out of my function